# Get block device model name and manufacturer from pseudo-fs

Tags: hard-disk, sysfs, hdparm

```
[gala@arch ~]$ sudo !!
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

 Model=KINGSTON SHFS37A120G, FwRev=603ABBF0, SerialNo=50026B725B0A1515
 Config={ HardSect NotMFM HdSw>15uSec Fixed DTR>10Mbs RotSpdTol>.5% }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=4
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=unknown, MaxMultSect=1, MultSect=1
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=234441648
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
 PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
 DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
 UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
 AdvancedPM=yes: unknown setting WriteCache=enabled
 Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-2,3,4,5,6,7

 * signifies the current active mode
```

Where does hdparm read the `Model` field from? Somewhere from `sysfs` ?  Where from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# strace hdparm -i /dev/sda
…
ioctl(3, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, 0x7fffa930c320) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1c42000
brk(0x1c63000)                          = 0x1c63000
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(1, " Model=…
```

So `hdparm` gets its information from the `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl), not from sysfs. That doesn't mean that the information can't be accessed from sysfs, of course.

Next we can look up `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` in the kernel source. [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident) is convenient for that. The relevant hit shows a [call to `ata_get_identity`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c?v=4.4#L706). This function [looks up the model](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c?v=4.4#L457) in the device description at the offset `ATA_ID_PROD` in the device description.

Looking at where else `ATA_ID_PROD` is used, and with sysfs in mind, we find a hit in [`ide-sysfs.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ide/ide-sysfs.c?v=4.4#L50), in a function called `model_show`. This function is referenced by the macro call just below [`DEVICE_ATTR_RO(model)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ide/ide-sysfs.c?v=4.4#L52), so if the ata driver is exposing the IDE interface, there's a file called `model` in the device's sysfs directory that contains this information.

If the ata driver is exposing the SCSI interface, tracing the kernel source is a lot more complicated, because the code uses different ways of extracting the information from the hardware. But as it turns out there is also [a `model` field](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c?v=4.4#L594) in the device's sysfs directory.

As for where the device's sysfs directory is, there are several ways to access it. The [`sysfs.txt` file in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) documents this, not very well. The simplest way to access it is via `/sys/block` which contains an entry for each block device:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/device/model
```

There are a lot of symbolic links in `/sys`. The “physical” location of that directory depends on how the disk is connected to the system; for example it has the form `/sys/devices/pci…/…/ata…/host…/target…/…` for an ATA device with a SCSI interface that's connected to a PCI bus.

Comment: This shows the difference between a hacker and a developer. A hacker like me tries to make stuff that works and has no idea what he is doing. A developer like you, knows exactly what he is doing and where to find what. Immacule info man, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it after an hour of digging:

```
gala@arch /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0 % pwd
/sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0
gala@arch /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0 % cat model
KINGSTON SHFS37A
```

So for the model:

```
/sys/bus/scsi/devices/<device>/model
```

And vendor:

```
/sys/bus/scsi/devices/<device>/vendor
```